Are ads already displayed on Italian SE?
I don’t currently see any ad on Italian SE. Is it just me or is this site not yet involved in the new ad policy? 

Feels more like a bug. Looked up the source and compared to some other beta sites and full sites - italian.SE is loading the ad script as well, and does have the ad containers, but for some reason, nothing loads. Interestingly, compared to a site with working ads, the loading stops after securepubads.g.doubleclick.net - none of the actual ads are loaded. Verified in two separate browsers in a logged out state and with all ad blockers and other blockers disabled. Might be disabled by SE, might be a bug - you'll need an employee to answer that.

Ads are not displayed on every site, typically only on the bigger ones. I'll try to figure out if there's an official list somewhere.

I looked into it a bit, and it seems that the answer is... it's complicated.
Ads are a priori on all sites, but this is not borne out in practice. There is however no official list on which sites have ads and which haven't, and I assume this depends on SE anyway: if they decided to add ads it would probably take just a click.
Furthermore, which ads you see, if any, depends also on your geographical location: if there are no ads available for your country, they simply won't display ads.
All in all it's really hard to figure out why some people get ads and some do not, and there's no real answer to the title question.

Thanks for your effort. I think advertiser are interested at the moment on Italy-based  users. (Luckily :).
